# Javascript indo pro inicio da página?

Tags: php, javascript

Galera, eu possuo um script de "Curtir" só que quando eu clico nele a página meio que da um reload e vai pro topo. Só que quando eu dou reload de fato na página, ela vai pro lugar que eu cliquei pra dar o "Like". O que pode ser isso?

Tudo está funcionando corretamente, a parte da contagem de curtidas, adicionar a curtida no banco de dados e tudo mais.. O que acontece mesmo é esse "bug" que a página não continua no mesmo lugar depois de eu clicar no botão de "Like".

Script:

```
function add_like(post_id, hora_post){
    $.post("init/add_like.php", {id_post:post_id, post_data:hora_post}, function(dados){
       if(dados == 5){
           get_like(post_id, hora_post);
       } 
    });
}
function get_like(post_id, hora_post){
    $.post("init/get_like.php", {id_post: post_id, post_data:hora_post}, function(valor){
        $('#post_'+post_id+'_like').text(valor);
    });
}
```

Página add_like.php:

```
session_start();
include("../functions.php");
include("../conecta.php");
$post_id = $_POST['id_post'];
$hora_post = $_POST['post_data'];
if(!verificar_clicado($conecta, $post_id, $_SESSION['id'])){
    if(adicionar_like($conecta, $post_id, $_SESSION['id'], $hora_post)){
        echo 5; // Valor para ser enviado para o arquivo JS 
    } 
}
```

Página get_like.php:

```
session_start();
include("../functions.php");
include("../conecta.php");
$post_id = $_POST['id_post'];
$numero_de_likes = retornar_likes($conecta, $post_id);
echo $numero_de_likes;
```

Botão de Curtir:

```
 <a href='' name="id" onclick="javascript:
            var dado1 = '<?=$post['id']?>';
            var dado2 = '<?=$post['hora']?>';
            add_like(dado1,dado2);
            " class="like-post">Like</a>
```

Botão que recebe os Likes:

```
<span id="post_<?=$post['id']?>_like">
                                <?php
                                    if($post['likes'] == 0){

                                    } else {
                                        echo $post['likes'];
                                    }
                                ?></span>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Troque a âncora do botão de curtir por um span. O href em branco é que está causando um rolamento para o topo da página.

Comment: Muito obrigado!!

Answer (score 0):

Caso você deseje continuar a usar a marcação âncora do html(`<a href="#">...</a>`) você pode simplesmente usar um `return false;` no final de sua função.

Exemplo:

```
function add_like(post_id, hora_post){
    $.post("init/add_like.php", {id_post:post_id, post_data:hora_post}, function(dados){
       if(dados == 5){
           get_like(post_id, hora_post);
       } 
    });
    return false;
}
```